# PHP class root directory

Tags: php, class, directory, root

anyone know how to create **php class root directory** just like wordpress does?
it doenst have to be like wordpress.
ive got some folders

```
*include:
 -header.php
 -footer.php
*images
*forms
 -index.php
```

the problem is when i use php `header` the image doesnt link up properly, is there anyway to solve it.
i read some article to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].` and how do i apply it globally?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're asking for? Are you trying to replicate WordPress' class loading strategy?

Comment: @Rob yeas something like. what about to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will it work globally?

Answer (score 1):

The least weird way i've managed to do it:

1. Add your app root (often `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]`) to the include_path (easily done in php.ini, apache config, or at runtime with `set_include_path`)
2. define an __autoload function to `require "classes/{$classname}.class.php"`

You may need to make the files' names lower case; i forget whether __autoload gets passed the class name as lower case, but i seem to remember issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an `include_path`. The `include_path` works like `$PATH` on Windows and UNIX. When you ask for a file (with require, or include), PHP will try to find it in the current directory. If it's not found, then will start trying with the directories defined in `include_path`.

`include_path` is a PHP.ini environment variable, so you can modify it in your main `php.ini` file, in your `.htaccess` using [`php_value`](http://support.tigertech.net/php-value), or runtime using [`set_inclue_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-include-path.php).

When you've added, for example, the `class` folder, then you can run `require('class/foo.php');` in any of your project's files, and it'll find your global class folder, only if you **don't** have another class folder there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it has much to do with what you are looking for, but just in case it helps: In most websites I do from scratch I include the necessary php files in different folders (depending on language, section, etc) with a simple code. From the URL, I get the language and the section and page variables:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$include_string = ":/$root:/$root/$lang:/$root/$lang/$section:/$root/$lang/$section/$page";
ini_set("include_path", ".:../:$include_string");
```

My code is a bit more complex because there are some more variables and shared folders, but it's just the same thing with some loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will work globally.

`$_SERVER` is one of PHP's [*superglobals*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).